# Sintaxis incorrecta en procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

He creado un procedure en `Sql Server` y me lanza error.

Ejecuto bien, pero a la hora de ingresarle un valor no lo reconoce.

En el procedure estoy asignado un `if` para que pueda devolver
una de las 2 consultas.

Quizás el procedure no esta correctamente definido.

```
Incorrect syntax near '1302000738'.
```

```
create PROCEDURE uspconciliacion
(
@mtcn varchar(11)
)
as
IF(LEN(@mtcn)=10)
BEGIN
    select re.CreadoFecha 'Fecha' ,
           concat(cli.apellidoPaterno,' ',cli.ApellidoMaterno) 'Apeliido Remitente' ,
           cli.nombre 'Nombre Remitente' ,
           concat(re.NombreDestino,' ',re.ApellidoPatDestino,' ',re.ApellidoMatDestino) 'Beneficiario',
           re.IdRemesa 'MTCN',
           re.CantidadEnvio 'IMP. Pagar',
           re.Itf 'I.T.F',
           re.CantidadRecibir 'Pincipal',
           cli.CodPaisResidencia 'Pais Remitente' 
      from Remesa re 
inner join Cliente cli 
        on re.IdCliente=cli.IdCliente 
     where re.IdRemesa=@mtcn
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select re.CreadoFecha 'Fecha' ,
           concat(re.ApellidoPatDestino,' ',re.ApellidoMatDestino) 'Apeliido Benefeciario' ,
           re.NombreDestino  'Nombre Beneficiario' ,
           concat(cli.Nombre,' ',cli.ApellidoPaterno,' ',cli.ApellidoMaterno)'Remitente' , 
           re.IdRemesa 'MTCN',
           re.Itf 'I.T.F',
           re.CantidadRecibir 'Pincipal', 
           re.Comision 'Cargo',
           re.Igv 'IGV',
           re.CantidadEnvio 'Total Envio',
           re.PaisPago
      from Remesa re 
inner join Cliente cli 
        on re.IdCliente=cli.IdCliente 
     where re.IdRemesa=@mtcn  
END
```

Ejecución del procedimiento:

```
uspconciliacion('1302000738')
```

Comment: No es la forma de invocar un SP, sino más bien `EXECUTE uspconciliacion  '1302000738'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se genera porque sobran los paréntesis.

Hay varias formas de llamar a un procedimiento, por ejemplo:

```
exec uspconciliacion '1302000738'
execute uspconciliacion '1302000738'
execute dbo.uspconciliacion '1302000738'
uspconciliacion '1302000738'
```

En este último caso, hago la aclaración que, como alternativa se puede llamar y ejecutar el procedimiento sin la palabra clave (Exec , Execute) si el procedimiento es la primera instrucción del lote de Transact-SQL. [Fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)